# How to delete selected row from database and datagridview

Tags: vb.net

i have data in my database, what happens is that when i select a row and right click it and then click delete, all rows having the same StudentNo get deleted from the datagridview and database. what i want is that only the selected row gets deleted from the database and datagridview. attached is an image of my data. 
[image: datagridview]

this is the code i have.

```
Try
        If Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            If Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
                Dim intStdID As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("StudentNO").Value
                'open connection
                If Not myconnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    myconnection.Open()
                End If

                'delete data
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
                cmd.Connection = myconnection
                cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM AlevelGeneralResults WHERE StudentNO=" & intStdID
                Dim res As DialogResult
                res = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to DELETE the selected Row?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
                If res = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Else : Exit Sub
                End If
                'refresh data
                refreshdgv()

                'close connection
                myconnection.Close()
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

Comment: First of all .. change Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("StudentNO").Value with Me.DataGridView1.CurrnetRow.Index to delete current row and change cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM AlevelGeneralResults WHERE StudentNO=" & intStdID  , find the record Id form database..

Comment: @CristiC777, i did not quite understand this part: change cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM AlevelGeneralResults WHERE StudentNO=" & intStdID , find the record Id form database.

Comment: I think you have a flow in your database design link .. to identify every row .. from DGV,  is easier with DataSet, and DataTable .. and Binding to DGV.

Answer (score 1):

You could use more criteria in your SQL to make the Row unique.

On the first look I would add the Columns Subject and BOTP1.

Your SQL would look like this:

```
DELETE FROM AlevelGeneralResults WHERE StudentNO=" & intStdID & " AND Subject='" & strSubject & "' AND BOTP1=" & intBotp
```

Before your must add two new variable beside intStdID

```
Dim intStdID As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("StudentNO").Value
Dim strSubject As String = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("Subject").Value
Dim intBotp As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("BOTOP1").Value
```

The best Way would be if you have an Index/ID which could make your data row unique. But in your screenshot has no visible column which could be the ID.

Comment: My primary key consists of StudentNo, Class, Term, Subject and year. i have tried your solution but it still deletes all rows with the same student number.

Comment: @SamuelRonald Do you thought about adding an ID Column which is alone unique? Like GUID or an consecutive number. With this you only needs to search for this Column and delete only this row.

Comment: Otherwise you must change the where to filter with your primary key.  `DELETE FROM AlevelGeneralResults WHERE StudentNO=? AND Class='?' AND Term='?' AND Subject='?' AND Year=?`

Comment: i had already tried that and it worked, i just didn't want to have to change my primary key but i guess am gonna have to go with this option. Thanks for the help.